# Netty - getRemoteAddress returns different port every time

Tags: java, port, netty

I am using [LittleProxy](http://www.littleshoot.org/littleproxy/) which implements [Netty](http://netty.io) .
I am trying to return the IP address and port of the source of an HTTP request.
I use the getRemoteAddress method, but the returned port is always different. It seems to add up after every request? I must be missing some insight here.

After some searching, I tried downcasting it to an InetSocketAddress. But the results are the same:

```
private void processRequest(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, 
        final MessageEvent me) {

        final HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) me.getMessage();
        //THOMAS EDIT FOR OUTPUT REMOTE ID AND PORT
        InetSocketAddress inetAddr = (InetSocketAddress)me.getRemoteAddress();        
        System.out.println("Source IP: " + inetAddr.getAddress());
        System.out.println("Source Port: " + inetAddr.getPort());
```

Comment: The getting port is always different for each new tcp connection, but it never change for the particular session.

Answer (score 2):

Netty behaves like a Gateway or NAT. the IpAddress and Ports it give are its own port numbers.

what you can try is to get the HTTPHeader `X-Forwarded-For`

Option 2:

use ChannelHandlerContext instead of MessageEvent

`ctx.getChannel().getRemoteAddress();`

Comment: Could this potentially be forged? (Because it's an HTTP field...) Or can you be sure because it was last added by the trusted netty library?

Comment: I only have "Via" in my HTTP request, and it seems to point to my local (netty) machine.

Comment: could you try `ctx.getChannel().getRemoteAddress();`

Comment: The ports keep jumping... Sometimes the port stays the same for a couple of requests. But it jumps more often than not. Must indeed be the internal NAT/Gateway. But how to get the original IP:PORT? 
Normally, should the X-Forwarded-For field be set by Netty?

Comment: port might not be reliable as Netty is orchestrating all tcp packets

Comment: would not work in case of proxies :), simply, against load balancers